# Pulling QGIS plugin logic into stand alone Application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-creator, qgis

I'm new to QT, Python, and QGIS. I installed the "Plugin Builder" plugin and generated a Dockwidget. I am able to change the widget using qtcreator and am learning how to implement the signals and slots to work with my own plugin.

Now, to my question. Is there and easy way I can remove the QGIS iface and use my plugin's logic outside of QGIS? I'm not actually using any of the PyQGIS libraries at the moment, but I want to keep my QT interface and Python code/structure generated by the "Plugin Builder". Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it. But so far what I have found is that we need to copy entire Qgis library to the final software package. It is very important to set the correct path for qgis application inside the code as follows:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
QgsProject.instance().setFileName(strProjectName)
```

Also we need to write the file and close it at the end

```
QgsProject.instance().write()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Here's snapshot of the stand alone package I have created. The code needs some modification for some variables to work.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import os, datetime

class CreateQgs():

    def initQgsFile(self, outputFolder, stopRadius):

        strProjectName = str(outputFolder) + "\\" + "PhotoLocationMap.qgs"
        QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis", True)
        QgsApplication.initQgis()
        QgsProject.instance().setFileName(strProjectName)

        highwayShapeFilePath = "C:/Shapefiles/Highway.shp"
        arterialShapeFilePath = "C:/Shapefiles/StreetsMajor.shp"

        highwayLayer = QgsVectorLayer(self.highwayShapeFilePath, 'HighwayDB' , 'ogr')
        arterialLayer = QgsVectorLayer(self.arterialShapeFilePath, 'ArterialDB', 'ogr')

        symbols = highwayLayer.rendererV2().symbols()
        sym = symbols[0]
        sym.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,94,94))
        highwayLayer.triggerRepaint()

        symbols = arterialLayer.rendererV2().symbols()
        sym = symbols[0]
        sym.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(76,138,245))
        arterialLayer.triggerRepaint()

        mapInstance = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

        mapInstance.instance().addMapLayer(arterialLayer)
        mapInstance.instance().addMapLayer(highwayLayer) 

        QgsProject.instance().write()
        QgsApplication.exitQgis()

def unitTest():
    app = QgsApplication(sys.argv, True)
    photoFolderPath = 'C:\Test\QGis\TestPics'
    CreateQgsFile = CreateQgs()
    CreateQgsFile.initQgsFile(photoFolderPath, 128)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unitTest()
```